# c# SQL with Lambda: Can't filter for multiple results

Tags: c#, sql, wpf, lambda

I'm having a issue where I'm trying to apply a where filter. This is not working as intended however.

It's about this line

> && fout.Omschrijving.Contains(textboxFilterOmschrijving.Text)

Now it's possible to return all results with a partial match to this one field. However i'm trying to make it so it can contain multiple words in one input field and it would then return all results matching to this.

The input would be separeted by a ',' then. Like so:

> List listMyOmschrijvingen =
>   textboxFilterOmschrijving.Text.Split(',').ToList();

Then there is searched for a match to these, only it seems to ignore the Contains property and goes only for a full match.

> && listMyOmschrijvingen.Contains(fout.Omschrijving)

This gives all these results as wanted. But the only thing is they need to be 100% precise. If I want all results with DEF_ACK and DEF_VOLT I would want to type ack, volt as input field "Omschrijving" and as result it gives all matching records from the SQL db.

Now it only does this when it's a 100% full match

For example I have to enter DEF_ACK,DEF_VOLT (a space would even mess the results up). Does anyone have a idea on how to solve this? Probably something really silly since it's so easy for one record but not for dynamically more.

```
FoutenResultaat =
(from x in treinen
join fout in fouten
on x.TreinId equals fout.TreinId
where dateStart <= fout.Datum && dateEnd >= fout.Datum 
&& treinenIds.Contains(fout.Treinen.Name)
&& fout.Omschrijving.Contains(textboxFilterOmschrijving.Text)
&& fout.FoutCode.Contains(textboxFilterFout.Text) 
&& fout.Module.Contains(textboxFilterModule.Text)

orderby fout.Datum descending, fout.Time descending

select new
{
    Datum = fout.Datum,
    Time = fout.Time,
    FoutCode = fout.FoutCode,
    Omschrijving = fout.Omschrijving,
    Module = fout.Module.ToUpper(),
    FoutId = fout.FoutId,
    Name = x.Name,
});
```

Comment: Can you provide an example of input, output and expected result? It's hard to follow your attempts without example and to understand what are you doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue here is that `string.Contains()` is a whole different method than `IEnumerable.Contains()`.  When you use `Contains()` on a string, it will look at the contents of that string to see if it contains the given `value`; this is why you get the partial match you were referring to.  On the other hand, using `Contains()` on a list will look for a full match on one of the items in the list.

Try this (added bonus: .Trim() for your space issue):

```
&& listMyOmschrijvingen.Where(l => fout.Omschrijving.Contains(l.Trim())).Any()
```